# goapp serve: seriously unstable with random 0xb01dfacedebac1e errors

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Currently trying out Google Cloud with Go, and I'm having the most bizarre issue I have ever seen.

I have made an ultra simple "hello world" app that just prints out some text to the browser. It compiles perfectly with "`go build`", and even deploys to Google Cloud and runs there just fine, but when I use "`goapp serve`" to run it locally it randomly crashes when I start it, with a huge stack trace and the message:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0xf47b]
```

When I get the error, I simply run "`goapp serve`" again, and after a few tries it somehow magically decides to work. Other times, if I can't get it to run after 10-20 tries, I simply make a micro change in the code somewhere, like editing a string, changing a single character, and then it runs just fine locally. Whaaaaat!?!?!?

I'm so baffled how this is even possible. I seems that "`goapp serve`" is extremely fragile. It's Google official local development server, so I would expect it to be a little more stable, or at least give some more human readable clues.

I have searched all over and can't find anything related to this.

Any ideas how or what is causing this?

Here is the stack trace:

```
ERROR   go_runtime.py:181] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /usr/local/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/kieran/Go/src/hello/main -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /usr/local/go_appengine/goroot -nobuild_files ^^$ -unsafe -gopath /Users/kieran/Go -binary_name _go_app -extra_imports appengine_internal/init -work_dir /var/folders/w3/wrcy8wfn3gzbnphs0cq6yw9r0000gn/T/tmpf_Nrsvappengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/usr/local/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine -ldflags -L,/usr/local/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine main.go)

fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0xf47b]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2c4ac0, 0x2a)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/panic.go:547 +0x90
runtime.sigpanic()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x5a
runtime.unlock(0x3aa0c0)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/lock_sema.go:107 +0x14b
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x3aa0c0, 0x1, 0x20000000020, 0x8a5178)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mheap.go:492 +0x314
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mheap.go:502 +0x41
runtime.systemstack(0xc820039e58)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:307 +0xab
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x3aa0c0, 0x1, 0x10000000020, 0xf11f)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mheap.go:503 +0x63
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0x3ac190, 0x0)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mcentral.go:209 +0x93
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x3ac190, 0x8a5178)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mcentral.go:89 +0x47d
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x406c20, 0x20, 0x8a5178)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/mcache.go:119 +0xcc
runtime.mallocgc.func2()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/malloc.go:642 +0x2b
runtime.systemstack(0xc820012000)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:291 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/proc.go:1051

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:245 fp=0xc8200329d0 sp=0xc8200329c8
runtime.mallocgc(0x480, 0x25c640, 0xc800000000, 0xc820074240)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/malloc.go:643 +0x869 fp=0xc820032aa8 sp=0xc8200329d0
runtime.newarray(0x25c640, 0x18, 0x152be8)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/malloc.go:798 +0xc9 fp=0xc820032ae8 sp=0xc820032aa8
runtime.makeslice(0x1e6920, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/slice.go:32 +0x165 fp=0xc820032b38 sp=0xc820032ae8
cmd/link/internal/ld.readsym(0xc820074240, 0xc825a9e1a0, 0xc821107850, 0x8, 0xc821ecb360, 0x4c)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/objfile.go:239 +0xba6 fp=0xc820032f80 sp=0xc820032b38
cmd/link/internal/ld.ldobjfile(0xc820074240, 0xc825a9e1a0, 0xc821107850, 0x8, 0xbf902, 0xc821ecb360, 0x4c)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/objfile.go:147 +0xa62 fp=0xc820033190 sp=0xc820032f80
cmd/link/internal/ld.ldobj(0xc825a9e1a0, 0xc821107850, 0x8, 0xbf93e, 0xc821ecb360, 0x4c, 0xc82326a050, 0x44, 0x1, 0x0)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/lib.go:1351 +0x1569 fp=0xc820033400 sp=0xc820033190
cmd/link/internal/ld.objfile(0xc82409ce70)
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/lib.go:847 +0x10d9 fp=0xc820033710 sp=0xc820033400
cmd/link/internal/ld.loadlib()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/lib.go:513 +0x5ce fp=0xc8200339f0 sp=0xc820033710
cmd/link/internal/ld.Ldmain()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/pobj.go:214 +0x1cd3 fp=0xc820033e70 sp=0xc8200339f0
cmd/link/internal/amd64.Main()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/internal/amd64/obj.go:44 +0x19 fp=0xc820033e78 sp=0xc820033e70
main.main()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/link/main.go:27 +0x36f fp=0xc820033f50 sp=0xc820033e78
runtime.main()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/proc.go:188 +0x2b0 fp=0xc820033fa0 sp=0xc820033f50
runtime.goexit()
    /private/var/folders/9y/ppk2fnqj5lscwqw_l6lhdrx8005bt1/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc820033fa8 sp=0xc820033fa0
```

Comment: This is likely either from an incorrect use of unsafe, or race conditions. Have you tested your code with the race detector?

Comment: I just added the stack trace. Race conditions do not show anything. I should mention that at first it appears to run as it's showing "serving" in the console for 2-3 seconds before it crashes, but looking at the stack trace it looks like it's choking at the compilation, which is really weird cause sometimes it does compile and run.

Comment: I really hope someone can shed some light on this. This is a boilerplate hello world app.

It's beyond me how running a few lines of Mux printing "hello" can cause the below message at random using `goapp serve`:

`fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x913aada46bc pc=0xf47b]`

How can running ´goapp serve´ consecutively, randomly work or fail, without any changes to anything?

It seems the local Google Cloud development server is screwed up?